# Connect and allow multiple ip's for mongodb accepting connections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a mongodb config file where bind ip is 127.0.0.1
Now mongodb is hosted on one instance and nodejs server is hosted on another instance which ip is (dummy ip) 184.54.125.132

On my mongodb Config file  is 
 net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0

By this my node server connect because it allows all (which is wrong)
How I add localhost ip of mongodb and my node server ip on bindIp so that mongodb server will listen only through node server and mongodb local.

```
I tried 
bindIP: [127.0.0.1,184.54.125.132] //Not work

I tried 
bindIp: 127.0.0.1,184.54.125.132 //Not work

I tried 
bind_ip: [127.0.0.1,184.54.125.132] //Not work

I tried 
bind_ip: 127.0.0.1,184.54.125.132 //Not work
```

Anyone suggest me where I am doing mistake. I also enabled authentication

Comment: Are you trying to use bindIP to whitelist clients?  That is not its purpose.

Comment: I want my mongodb access only to selected ip

Comment: Then bindIP will not do what you want.  The purpose if bindIP is to tell Mongodb which interfaces to listen for connections on, not which addresses to accept connections from.

Comment: Dear @PeterVC I want the security that my mongo is in contact with only node server and local access (Mongodb server acess i.e 127.0.0.1). I am on aws ec2 instance

Answer (score 1):

It should be :

```
bindIp : 127.0.0.1,184.54.125.132
```

And **dont forget to restart your mongod**, after changing the config file, otherwise it wont work.

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

or

```
sudo systemctl mongod restart
```

.
Also, **dont forget to open the port** so that outside network can access that port(27017 or whatever port your mongodb is hosted on).

If you are using AWS EC2 to host your mongodb, you need to add that port to your inbound security rules, and that specific IP wherever you want to access it from

Comment: yes i am using aws. and my current inbount is anywhere which i want to change. Dear I want to access my mongodb database only for local(ec2 machine instance) and my node server. If I connect through other ip then mongo not allow to make a connection. Please help me for that

Comment: Did you restart your `mongod` after changing the config file? And what do you mean 'my inbound is anywhere'? It cant be anywhere, you have to specify the port and which IP can access, in the AWS security rules

Comment: Dear @Ravi Shankar Yes I restart mongod. Currently I am testing that's why using anywhere means 0.0.0.0/0

Comment: bindIp : 127.0.0.1,184.54.125.132 after doing this when I restart my mongodb through command then it will not start. I checked the mongodb status it returns the error i.e "mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2019-03-28 09:38:27 UTC; 8s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3329 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=48)
 Main PID: 3329 (code=exited, status=48)"

Comment: Ravi - he wants to whitelist certain IP addresses.  BindIp will not do this.

Comment: @PeterVC I think that is what bindIp is for, it tells MongoDb which IPs should be allowed to access.

Comment: Unfortunately not.  If your Mongo server has multiple IPs then bindIP is set to which IPs you want Mongo to listen to.